# How can I store user session when using Symfony's BrowserKit component?

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am developing a tool that scrapes grades from the user's university profile. Currently, I am utilizing BrowserKit (HttpBrowser implementation). When a user inputs their login credentials into my form, the HttpBrowser client simply submits a form on the university website. How can I store this session so that the user does not have to re-enter their credentials for future actions, such as refreshing the page.

I am using Symfony6.